# Connect my application with Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating an application using ObjC and cocos2d, and I would like to connect my app via button with a link of the Facebook application. 
How can I do this? (I want that when the button is pressed, it opens the page of Facebook application.)

Comment: do you want to login with Facebook or do you want to open Facebook page on a web view?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you want to login using Facebook, take a look at this [website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.4).

All kinds of information and tutorials in there on the subject of Facebook integration in your programs.

Answer (score 2):

You should drop a [Facebook iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) into the project, follow the guide and document on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Try using parse.com, it's really simple

https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios